# Cannot resolve project reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am building a .NET WPF application, which was previously targeting .NET 4.6.1.

I have used this [tool](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) to convert my previous .csproj into the new Package-Reference csproj style of VS2017.

I have also updated the target framework to .NET 4.7.1.

The issue is that my main project references other projects from my solution, and each of those fails when I declare *using namespace;*

When I was using the previous csproj style projects, my main project was successfully referencing my other projects inside my solution but it does not anymore.

I have tried disabling ReSharper and I've even checkout the sources to a from scratch Windows installation and I got the same thing.

The weird thing is I got many errors from Intellisense, but everything builds **perfectly**!

I am running out of idea...

The solution sources are [here](https://github.com/bbougot/Popcorn).

[image: Caption]

Comment: My crystall ball says: "What is your budget to fix all of it."  Live is not so easy. Dump code and expect SO users fix it for free :)

Comment: I assume you have tried removing and re-adding the dependencies?

Comment: @Eser Do you expect me to rewrite my entire solution into SO?

Comment: @MortenBork Yes, removing/readding projects does not have any effect.

Comment: @Ben I expect you to read what and how to ask here....

Comment: @Eser The issue is not juste a "sample" of code, it is linked to the entire hierarchy of a .NET solution composed of 7 projects. I have given the best info I can, and even the sources if someone care digging into it.

Comment: @Ben So you want us to download the whole code, fix the bug and post the answer just because we love you. Maybe you want to read http://sscce.org/ or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: @Eser Maybe you can understand I'm just looking for help and I don't really know what code may I post, given this issue could come from *anywhere*. But I can remove the Github link if it bothers you that mutch (or simply ignore it).

Comment: @Ben good luck for you(See I still didn't downvote or vote to close this question) I am also curious about the answers

Comment: Hi. I just downloaded your code. And you have customized ignoring a few errors and warnings. That's not smart. Second of all, you have conflicting versions of the same depend assembly added. That is likely what is causing your trouble.

If you go to the project properties, and the build tab. Remove suppress warnings, and treat all warnings as errors. When  you build, you get a shit ton of things you have to fix. Start there maybe?

Comment: I have unmuted every warning and considered them as errors. I simply had two of them regarding Task being not awaited. Fixed them, rebuilt successfully and still have the same unresolved symbols.

Comment: 7 projects isn't so many.  Have you tried taking a good long stare at the text of the .csproj files?  Or simply rebuilt your solution from scratch?  Even 7 complex projects should be reconstructable in a working day with the source available.  It sucks, but....

Comment: How do .NET Core and Asp.net Core factor into this?

Comment: What version of VS? It is a Roslyn issue (false alarm), and should have been fixed in latest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The weird thing is I got many errors from Intellisense, but everything builds perfectly!

well assuming this is the case - intellisense information is stored beside your solution-file in the `.vs` folder. You can try to close VS, remove the folder and reopen the solution. This usually fixes my problems when dealing Intellisense errors despite successfull builds.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this basic advice: When you have a using statement, you're citing a namespace. In order for that namespace to be resolved, the project in question must have a **reference** to an assembly or project that contains that namespace. The fact that your `DownloadService.cs` code module shows that it cannot resolve the Popcorn.Utils namespace tells me that the project that contains `DownloadService.cs` does not have a reference to the project or assembly that contains Popcorn.Utils.